# EF-Core: Table "name" already exists - when trying to update database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

ASP Core 3.1 - API. I'm using the latest version of Entity Framework Core.

I have created a table `ToDoItem` and a `ToDoItemContext`. After creating the initial migration, and running `update-database`. I now have that table in my database. I now added a new model called: `ToDoItemDescription`.

When I try to update the database after creating a new migration, I get the error:

> Table 'todoitems' already exists

Further details: I have two contexts, and this is the command I ran:

```
update-database -context todoitemscontext
```

I also tried:

```
update-database -context todoitemscontext -migration AddDescription
```

Here is my full code:

Models:

```
public class TodoItem : IEntity 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}

public class ToDoItemDescription 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //public int ToDoItemId { get; set; }
    public TodoItem TodoItem { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public class TodoItemsContext : DbContext 
{
   public TodoItemsContext(DbContextOptions<TodoItemsContext> options) : base(options) { }

   public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }
   public DbSet<ToDoItemDescription> TodoItemsDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Migrations:

```
[DbContext(typeof(TodoItemsContext))]
partial class TodoItemsContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot 
{
    protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    #pragma warning disable 612, 618
    modelBuilder
        .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "3.1.9")
        .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 64);
    modelBuilder.Entity("project.Models.ToDoItemDescription", b => {
        b.Property<int>("id")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .HasColumnType("int");
        b.Property<string>("Description")
        .HasColumnType("longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
        b.Property<long?>("TodoItemId")
        .HasColumnType("bigint");
        b.HasKey("id");
        b.HasIndex("TodoItemId");
        b.ToTable("TodoItemsDescription");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity("project.Models.TodoItem", b => {
        b.Property<long>("Id")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .HasColumnType("bigint");
        b.Property<bool>("IsComplete")
        .HasColumnType("tinyint(1)");
        b.Property<string>("Name")
        .HasColumnType("longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
        b.HasKey("Id");
        b.ToTable("TodoItems");
    });
    modelBuilder.Entity("project.Models.ToDoItemDescription", b =>
    {
    b.HasOne("project.Models.TodoItem", "TodoItem")
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("TodoItemId");
    });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
}

public partial class TodoItems_Initial : Migration
{
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "TodoItems",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    IsComplete = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_TodoItems", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "TodoItems");
        }
    }

public partial class AddDescription : Migration
{
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "TodoItemsDescription",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    TodoItemId = table.Column<long>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_TodoItemsDescription", x => x.id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_TodoItemsDescription_TodoItems_TodoItemId",
                        column: x => x.TodoItemId,
                        principalTable: "TodoItems",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_TodoItemsDescription_TodoItemId",
                table: "TodoItemsDescription",
                column: "TodoItemId");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "TodoItemsDescription");
        }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Delete the `TodoItems_Initial` migration class and see what happens.

Comment: Alright. Is it safe to do so? Since it was auto-generated in my first migration. Thanks.

Comment: It is always better to take a backup before making changes that are suspicious.

Comment: @JamshaidKamran
It worked. But why, and will I have to do this every time I update my models? Thanks.

Comment: no, This happens if you delete the __MigrationHistory table, so the migrations that are not in the table will be re posted to the db, in your case you had the table but the __MigrationHistory table was cleared.

Comment: But shouldn't the _MigrationHistory records still be available?

Comment: No, MigrationHistory will sync your Migrations folder in the project, if you have class in it and there is no entry for the same class/table in the MigrationHistory it will execute the `Up();` method which tries to create the table.

Comment: I see. But since I deleted the TodoItems_Initial  migration. How would I be able to revert ? Since I no longer have it in my project.

Comment: @JamshaidKamran Can you make an answer so that I may accept your answer for my post? I want to mark this as solved, but I can't do it with your comments.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It could possible help people working with MySQL databases either on Linux and Windows**

#### TL;DR;

I had to rename the table

- `__efmigrationshistory` (note the lowercase) to
- `__EFMigrationsHistory` (note the case)

so the command-line `dotnet-ef database update` managed to verify all the migrations present on the table `__EFMigrationsHistory`, and therefore, creating the new field on the table, say *Tenant*

**More**

- I have to work on Linux, Windows, MacOs boxes. Primarily using Visual Studio code and .net core 3.1.xxx
- I use the code-first approach. The MySQL database was firstly, create on the Windows box, where all the tables were created lower cased
- Switching to the Linux box, I realized the case was important, so, say, table "tenant" was renamed to "Tenant", by hand.
- Once I had to create a new field on the Tenant's c# class, I ran:
  `dotnet-ef migrations add new-ftpSettings-field` and `dotnet-ef database update`, I got table "Order" already exists. *Note I was trying to insert a new field to the "Tenant" table*
- After a lot of investigation and search, I decided to refresh the database again, and I saw "two suspicious tables" **__efmigrationshistory** and **__EFMigrationsHistory**.
- I renamed the empty table **__EFMigrationsHistory** to like **Table1** (as a backup), and thus renamed the table **__efmigrationshistory** to **__EFMigrationsHistory**
- I ran the `dotnet-ef database update` and the field was properly added to the MySQL database.

*** Like you might have figured this out, running  the command-line `dotnet-ef database update` on Linux was creating a new (and) empty table **__EFMigrationsHistory** to MySQL database while it had already, a  lower cased table on  **__efmigrationshistory** (the good one, created on my Windows box, with all the migrations).

*** This is my first contribution. Any advice is welcome!

Keep safe! Tchau/Au revoir!

Answer (score 24):

This happens if you have created the database upfront without migrations, for example by using `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();`.

Comment: That much is true. I accidentally called `EnsureCreated` instead of `Migrate`. Question is, how to proceed now? Should I delete the database? The migrations? Both? Something else?

Comment: this is very bad design, I thought `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` would get me away from boilerplate code and in the long run it will cause me problems, _sigh_ now I have no choice but figure this out with my 30GB SQLite db, why doesn't it just automatically create the table itself?

Answer (score 9):

This usually happens when you have a migration that creates a table and the required table is already present in your database so, when you update the database from classes in Migration, it will try to create a table and will fail because the Create command will not be executed as it already has that specific table.

So, in order to avoid the error, you might want to remove the migration class or comment the code in `Up()` method of that class so it doesn't execute that specific create command.

Answer (score 7):

The issue with migrations is it reapplies any migrations that are not captured in `_EFMigrationsHistory` table.

Those are the migrations in Visual Studio, I am trying to apply migration_02 ONLY, but it keeps running migration_01 which causes similar issues!

[image]

When looking at `_EFMigrationsHistory`, it's obviously way off!

[image]

I took a risk and modified the data to: (using migration_01 full name)

[image]

Finally! managed to run the migration, only migration_02 changes applied, and the table now shows:

[image]

Comment: Giving you an upvote. This is the solution that helped me a lot. I did not change DB values but the migration class name and Migration attribute string. I had the same configuration, but between I accidentally rewrote PostgreSql with MSSql setup, which cause multiple errors until I found out what is happening.

Comment: In my case, the version was correct but somehow the migration name was different. Changing the name to the one in VS fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was working through the [migration tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) and had made a mistake sometimes around these steps

```bash
    dotnet ef migrations add AddBlogCreatedTimestamp
    dotnet ef database update
```

I did the following

1. deleted the files `AddBlogCreatedTimestamp.Designer.cs` and `AddBlogCreatedTimestamp.cs`
2. inside `blogging.db` in the table `__EFMigrationsHistory` i deleted the row that contains `2023__***__AddBlogCreatedTimestamp` this was the migration step that failed.
3. I repeated the migration step `dotnet ef migrations add ...`
4. then manually added `DropTable(...)` to `AddBlogCreatedTimestamp.Up()`
5. only then i ran `dotnet ef database update`

This made sure that in an up-migration the tables would be deleted

#### Code manually changed

```cs
public partial class AddBlogCreatedTimestamp : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
       // manually added
       migrationBuilder.DropTable(name: "Posts");
       migrationBuilder.DropTable(name: "Blogs");
       // ... other lines that were created
    }
    
    // more other code ...
}
```

What i still not get is why this is needed. I am not aware to have used anything like `EnsureCreated`